# Sending email from gmail using CakePHP3, Connection refused

Tags: cakephp, smtp, cakephp-3.0

I am having a problem with configuration with CakePHP3 for sending email from my Gmail account. I always get an error `Connection refused`. I don't know where the problem is. So I hope anyone here has any knowledge about sending emails from my Gmail account.

EDIT: I am using GoDaddy hosting server

Here are my configurations.

```
'gmail' => [
            'host' => '(ssl://)smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'username' => 'MyGmail@gmail.com', 
            'password' => 'pass',
            'className' => 'Smtp',
            'tls' => true
        ],





    'Email' => [
        'gmail' => [
            'transport' => 'gmail',
            'from' => 'myGmail@gmail.com',
            //'charset' => 'utf-8',
            //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

First update email config in CakePHP

Your Updated config/app.php  file should be as :

```
      'EmailTransport' => [
         'default' => [
           'className' => 'Smtp',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'username@domain.com',
            'password' => 'your_password',
         ],
      ],
```

and now use the mail function of CakePHP Email Function.

Comment: I have everything as you wrote above,however,  the error is still the same:
CONNECTION REFUSED on this line
 if (!$this->_socket->connect()) {
            throw new SocketException('Unable to connect to SMTP server.');
        }

Comment: @modivno - you need also to check if you have "less secure apps" allowed on your gmail - check https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879 for instructions

Comment: @Szymon Do I need to buy G-suite plan? Because the link you provided redirects me to the G-suite?

Comment: @modivno - no, you do not need to. Its also available for normal accounts: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: it is on, do you think that the problem is that my domain is HTTP and does not support ssl?

Comment: @modivno  login with your google account and go to the link: https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1#connectedapps

There is a section "Allow less secure apps" . Please enable it to send emails. 

Another options to send email without enabling it is create a new app password. Refer link for more info: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en